# Javascript detects visitor origin/referer

Tags: http-referer, referer

Understand that we can use `document.referrer` in JavaScript to detect where a visitor came from on the web browser.

Wondering if there's any mechanism using JavaScript to detect if the visitor arrived at the website by clicking on the link of a mobile app (e.g. Facebook)?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps won’t send referrers. Smartphone apps are unable to pass “referring page” information to your site analytics. So direct traffic stats may be inflated.

Your best bet is to add a querystring in the links and then check that.

Ie.

```
https://www.yoursite.com?ref=facebook
```

index.html

```
<script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const ref = urlParams.get('ref');

switch(ref) {
  case "facebook":
    // Count Facebook 
    break;
  case "snapchat":
    // Count Snapchat 
    break;
  default:
    // Count misc 
    break;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Goal of the implementation is to limit access origin to only facebook, i.e. user must click on the link via facebook to access the web page, copy and paste the link onto browser manually should not work.

Comment: You could generate a unique token/guid hashed with a secret for each user and add that to the querystring and only allow visitors that come from a link which has been decoded with correct secret.